# Android - Create Progress Dialog

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, dialog

I am new to android development. I want to develop a `dialog` with a `progressbar` in my application. When i click the search button the `dialog` should appear with the `progressbar`, showing that the progress is going on before switching to another `activity`. Please suggest me with sample code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `ProgressDialog`. You should do the work on a new `thread`, though, and use a `handler` to call back to the `activity` when finished. Here's how I do it:

```
private ProgressDialog pd;

private View.OnClickListener searchClick = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "Searching...", "Searching for matches", true, false);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //do work
                //.....

                finishedHandler.sendEmptyMessage();
                }
            }).start();
    }
}

private Handler finishedHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        pd.dismiss();
        //start new activity
    }
}
```